# Fighting with auto layout

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, constraints

I want this to work on all iPhones from 4 to 6+ portrait only.

Look at this autolayout designed for iPhone 4:

[image]

This imageView has an aspect ratio of 49:59 and has to keep this constant.

The imageView is inside a UIView container (the orange box). The orange container is attached to the 4 corners with 0 space. On the bottom part of the interface, another container (the white one) that contains 4 sliders.

This is the constraints I have applied to that imageView: top, bottom, leading, trailing to the orange container and aspect ratio 49:59.

This is how it scales to other iPhone screens:

[image]

but I don't want that. Look of how much screen is wasted on bigger iPhones.

What I want is the imageView to scale until it touches the left and right borders.

I want this:

[image]

There is plenty room for the view to scale and touch the left and right borders on big iphones while still keeping the same aspect ratio.

What kind of constraints should I apply to the imageView to do that? I have tried everything.

Comment: What constant values do you have for the leading and trailing constraints between the image view and the orange view?

Comment: 38 and 37 but I have tried to change that to >= 0 but the image expands to bigger than the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of fighting I got it to work. The constraints to the imageView are:

centerX, centerY, trailing and leading both >= 0, top and bottom both >= 3 and aspect ratio locked to 49:59.

This auto layout thing is the opposite of something intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but I think it should work, if you give the image view constraints to the left and right sides of the orange view with constant values of 0 (or some other small number if you want a little orange showing), a centerY constraint, and the aspect ratio constraint.

Comment: that works for all iphones except for iPhone 4. On iphone 4 the image bleeds on the vertical.

Comment: @RubberDuck, what doe mean by "bleeds"? Are you testing on an actual device, because it looks fine to me on the 4s simulator.

Comment: expands vertically beyond the orange container. This autolayout thing is a joke.

Comment: @RubberDuck, Well, that's going to happen if the orange view is shorter than 385 (59/49 * 320).

Comment: so you are confirming that auto layout is really a joke. It cannot do the layout I want. fantastic.

Comment: @RubberDuck, no, I think you just don't understand it. It will do what you tell it to, and it can't do everything. What is the height of the orange view on an iPhone 4 sized screen?

Comment: I understand it and it is a joke. The height on iPhone 4 is 309. Keeping the imageView aspect ratio constant, the view can be expanded on bigger iPhones to touch the sides. The images you see here, of the view expanded, have the same aspect ratio, so it is possible. Auto layout is the one that is poorly designed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63286/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-rubberduck).

Comment: got it to work after hours fighting. See my answer. Thanks for your help. You were awesome!